# Creating a Web Content in Liferay 7: Where is the rich text editor?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

we tried to create a new web content in liferay 7 and we were pretty surprised because we couldn´t find the rich text editor any more.
Is there a special trick to activate it ?
We have lots and lots of web contents that need html code ...

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site Please don't crosspost without linking. Grrr

Comment: I am so sorry Mr Kock ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing by

> we couldn´t find the rich text editor

you actually mean you didn't find CKEditor that was used in previous versions. If so, that is because Liferay 7 uses [AlloyEditor](http://alloyeditor.com/) instead. It is "rich text editor" just different one. This [live demo](http://alloyeditor.com/demo/) will help you understand how it works. Additionally in Liferay can see the html code by clicking on `</>` button located at editor's top right corner.

Comment: Yes - that's true. But how to I let our authors add bold, italic text or headlines? They won't add html markup. Is there any wysiwyg functionality in the web contents section?

Comment: Did you check the demo? It teaches you exactly that. Simply select a word or a phrase and menu will pop up next to it with relevant options.

Comment: Haven't checked it yet but will do now  thanks a lit for your help!